# How function match in scala?

Tags: scala

```
case class Person(name:String,age:Int)

val p1 = Person("Maria",18)

def h(x:Person) = x match{
 case y if y.age >17 => "Adult"
 case z if z.age <=17 => "Younger"  
}
```

Why in the cases it refers to the age with y or z if the parameter containing the values ​​is x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because `case y` means pattern everything and name the variable `y`, so it is basically creating a new variable that refers to the same object.
However, this is a poor use of pattern matching.

A better alternative would be:

```
def h(person: Person): String = person match {
  case Person(_, age) if (age > 17) => "Adult"
  case _ => "Younger" // Checking the age here is redudant.
}
```

Or just use `if / else`:

```
def h(person: Person): String =
  if (person.age > 17) "Adult"
  else "Younger"
```

Comment: I'd disagree that the first alternative is better; changes to `Person`'s definition are a lot more likely to break it.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Well, some may consider that a good thing, since changes on data model are usually meaningful. But, I do not want to discuss that. With _"better"_ in this case, I meant about the use of pattern matching, because the original code wasn't really pattern matching anything. And for that reason, I also propose the `if / else` alternative which is shorter and more readable.